# Exception: com.soomla.store.exceptions.VirtualItemNotFoundException: Virtual item was not found when searching with

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, soomla

I am using Soomla IAP plugin for `Unity3d` iOS platform and I have created itemId on iTunes store.

But when I try to run on unity Editor I am getting this exception:

> Exception: com.soomla.store.exceptions.VirtualItemNotFoundException:
>   Virtual item was not found when searching with
>   itemId="com.-----.coin200"

Answer (score 0):

For in app to work, you need to run the app on device then it will fetch it from the server.